# How to express symmetry of a mixed (1,1) tensor with upper and lower index?

Tags: metric-tensor, symmetry, tensor-calculus, notation

In the context of general relativity, I am working with the energy-momentum tensor $T$, which is a rank-2 tensor whose components are usually denoted by $T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$. However, I am unsure of how to write the fact that this tensor is symmetric. Which of the following two ways is correct?

$$T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}=T^\nu_{\ \ \ \mu}\ \ \ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ \ \ T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}
=T_\nu^{\ \ \mu}$$

I am thoroughly confused by this staggered indices notation, and would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second equality is the correct one. One way to see this is as follows:

$T^\mu{}_\nu = g^{\rho \mu} T_{\rho\nu} = g^{\rho \mu} T_{\nu\rho} = T_\nu {}^\mu$

here we use that we can raise indices with the metric in the first definition, then the definition of symmetry for $(2,0)$ tensors (which I think is a lot more intuitive), and then raise the index again.

One way to see why the first can never work is that whatever happens on both sides of the equality the same indices have to be upstairs/ downstairs so writing something like $T^\mu{}_\nu = T^\nu{}_\mu$ never makes any sense! Think of it after contraction: Take $V^\nu$ a vector and contract the equation with it :
$V^\nu T^\mu{}_\nu =V^\nu T^\nu{}_\mu$. However, this equation does not make sense at all what does it mean to contract two raised indices? It doesn't mean anything as it is not valid!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer. You say the second equality is the correct one, but you proved the first one. Also, the last step of your proof seems a bit strange, I don't believe that it is true, what you would obtain is again $T^\mu_{\ \ \ \ \nu}$, not $T^\nu_{\ \ \ \mu}$. Could you please explain this?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in the last step, just edited the answer to fix this. So the idea is that after switching the lowered indices the metric raises $\rho$ which is now at the second position so you do indeed get the second version of the statment